# Bulk add all Maven libraries to classpath in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've recently cloned a project and run `mvn clean install` which has installed all the dependencies listed in my the `pom.xml`. Whenever I open a class I see a lot of import statements that are trying to import a third party class are highlighted with the error `cannot resolve symbol Foo`. When I Alt+Enter there is an option to add the library to the classpath which completely resolves the issue - for this library:

[image]

This would be fine but I have many libraries I need to do this for. Is there a way I can do this in bulk?

**EDIT**

It's been brought to my attention that I shouldn't have to do this after a `mvn clean install` if that command completes successfully. As such this is the error I'm getting as the very last part of my logs:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ has good [Maven support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html). You should **not** have to add these dependencies into IntelliJ project manually if you imported the project from Maven `pom.xml`. Make sure you are selecting `Import project from external model` option when importing.

Does your project build with `mvn clean install`? If not, make sure that it does before changing anything in IntelliJ. Afterwards re-import the project into IntelliJ and double check `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven` configuration e.g. ensure that you are using the same Maven installation in command line and IntelliJ.

Perhaps you have something extra in your `settings.xml` configuration that makes it work in the command line but fails in IntelliJ when it runs with embedded Maven?

Comment: `mvn clean install` exits with an exit code of 0, and all the modules are marked as successful but it does throw `Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils` as the last thing it does. Maybe this could be it.

Comment: @Nanor always safer to fix errors and warnings in command line build before using IDE. Either way this should work out of the box unless you are doing some magic e.g. unpacking dependency JARs from a ZIP downloaded over HTTPS.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll see if fixing the NoClassDefFoundError fixes this issue and if it does I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Nanor your error comes from a Tomcat maven plugin which is not part of the standard build life cycle. At this point I'd adivse to delete `.idea` and `.iml` files and clearly re-import the project.